# SSL error when using Python/Zeep to retrieve registered phone from CM

Tags: python, zeep

I try to get the registered phone information from CUCM(ver10.5 and 11.5), copied code from this thread

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.cache import SqliteCache
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from lxml import etree
import urllib3
from urllib3 import disable_warnings
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
username = 'xxxx'
password = 'xxxx'
wsdl = 'https://x.x.x.x:8443/realtimeservice2/services/RISService70?wsdl'
session = Session()
session.verify = False
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
transport = Transport(cache=SqliteCache(), session=session, timeout=20)
history = HistoryPlugin()
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=transport, plugins=[history])
factory = client.type_factory('ns0')
macs = ['*'] #'*' for all
item=[]
for mac in macs:
item.append(factory.SelectItem(Item=mac))
Item = factory.ArrayOfSelectItem(item)
stateInfo = ''
criteria = factory.CmSelectionCriteria(
MaxReturnedDevices = 1000,
DeviceClass='Phone',
Model=255, #255 for all
Status='Registered',
NodeName='',
SelectBy='Name',
SelectItems=Item,
Protocol='Any',
DownloadStatus='Any'
)
result = client.service.selectCmDevice(stateInfo, criteria)
```

I got below error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\deviceStatus.py", line 20, in <module>
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=transport, plugins=[history])
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\zeep\client.py", line 76, in __init__
self.wsdl = Document(wsdl, self.transport, settings=self.settings)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 92, in __init__
self.load(location)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 95, in load
document = self._get_xml_document(location)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 155, in _get_xml_document
return load_external(
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\zeep\loader.py", line 89, in load_external
content = transport.load(url)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\zeep\transports.py", line 123, in load
content = self._load_remote_data(url)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\zeep\transports.py", line 135, in _load_remote_data
response = self.session.get(url, timeout=self.load_timeout)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 602, in get
return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.10.10.150', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: /realtimeservice2/services/RISService70?wsdl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER] sslv3 alert illegal parameter (_ssl.c:1002)')))
```

It looks like the CM does not like the parameters provided by the script, but I could not find any useful information about how to correct it.